# PayPal CreateRecurringPaymentProfile Error 11502 - Invalid Token

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I am setting up a Recurring Payment with PayPal's API.  First I send the following parameters to `SetExpressCheckout`:

```
Array
(
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [USER] => XXX
    [PWD] => XXX
    [SIGNATURE] => XXX
    [VERSION] => 98.0
    [AMT] => 0
    [MAXAMT] => 99.00
    [RETURNURL] => http://google.com
    [CANCELURL] => http://google.com
    [L_BILLINGTYPE0] => RecurringPayments
    [L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0] => 99.00 per month till stopped
)
```

This generates a response like the following:

```
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-90P39652RF345525U
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-02-08T17:09:24Z
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 98.0
)
```

Using the description and token from the created billing agreement, I send the following parameters to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile:

```
Array
    (
    [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
    [USER] => XXX
    [PWD] => XXX
    [SIGNATURE] => XXX
    [TOKEN] => EC-90P39652RF345525U
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => Feb 22 2013 17:09:24
    [DESC] => 99.00 per month till stopped
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 12
    [AMT] => 99.00
    [CURRENTCYCODE] => USD
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => VISA
    [ACCT] => 1234123412341234
    [EXPDATE] => 012014
    [CVV2] => 123
    [EMAIL] => fake@example.com
    [STREET] => 123 Main St
    [CITY] => New York City
    [STATE] => NY
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [ZIP] => 12345
)
```

All looks well to me, but it fails:

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-02-08T17:09:24Z
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 98.0
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11502
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Token
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The token is invalid
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tried updating the `PROFILESTARTDATE` to `'2013-02-22T17:27:03'` (with the T found in PayPal examples).  No luck, not surprisingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redirect the buyer to PayPal to approve the recurring payment before you call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.  The timestamps on both of your API responses are the same, which tells me that you called CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile as soon as you got your response from SetExpressCheckout.  You need to redirect the buyer to PayPal after you get your response back from SetExpressCheckout.

Comment: I literally just found this, not sure why it wasn't in the documentation.  A quick question..is there any way to initiate a recurring payment without having users go to PayPal and using their account? +1 for looking closely at the timestamps.

Comment: There's a couple of options.  1) PayPal Payments Pro with Recurring Billing.  This will only work for buyers using a credit card -- buyers using their PP account would still have to approve the recurring payment on the PP website.  It'll also run you about $60 a month.  2) Billing agreements (BAs).  With BAs, the buyer has to go to PP the first time to approve the BA, but they don't have to go back to the PayPal website after that -- you can just charge against the BA as needed.  Not automatic though -- you'd have to run an API call to process each charge.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Can you link me to any documentation/resources for PayPal Payments Pro w/Recurring Billing?  This is what I originally thought you could do with recurring payments, but it currently is forcing me to go through the PayPal BA.

Comment: I figured it out. You just have to go through CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and don't use a token.  Wish the documentation was better so I didn't have to waste my time with that all.

Comment: For anyone looking, here is a link to the related classic api (not the new rest api) doc https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/ This explains that you must redirect the user to paypal before creating the recurring payments profile. I didn't realise this either, but it's quite clear when I didn't just skim read. If you're using PHP, download (composer) the SDK and try the examples. Worked for me.